# Does a monk's Unarmed Strikes deal 2d4 damage if they have the Tavern Brawler feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, monk, damage, stacking

If a monk gets the *tavern brawler* feat, does his *martial arts* damage stack with the 1d4 damage given with tavern brawler?
For example: could a 1st level monk deal 2d4 damage with his unarmed strikes if he had the *tavern brawler* feat?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## No, they don't.

From the Monk's [Martial Arts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/monk#MartialArts) feature:

> You can roll a d4 in place of the normal damage of your unarmed strike or monk weapon.

From the [Tavern Brawler](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/tavern-brawler) feat (PHB, p. 170):

> Your unarmed strike uses a d4 for damage.

Both abilities replace the unarmed strike damage die; they don't add to it. So if you have both abilities, you would still only roll 1d4 (plus Dex or Str mod).

Comment: I suggest expanding a bit to point out what happens when the monk's martial arts die changes size.

Comment: If they have both abilities, why wouldn't they choose which one to use?